# Cross Origin issue in the react build files

Tags: reactjs

I hosted (Apache server) my react build files  successfully. After I checked login page and its working as I expected. But When  I try to login below error occurred.

[image]

my react js config file is as below.

```
import { isLocalhost } from "serviceWorker";

let SERVER = isLocalhost
  ? "http://localhost:8082"
  : "http://120.162.10.125:5000";
```

How I fix this issue. Thanks you